# Как за 1 секунду сделать фиксированное количество повторений некоторой функции в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Как за 1 секунду сделать фиксированное количество повторений некоторой функции в Python?

Comment: Че-то не понятно , рекурсия что-ли?А одна секунда тут причем ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval

Comment: Для этого лучше использовать декоратор. Вот хороший пример - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368571/10691794

Answer (score 1):

Вызвать её в цикле for i in range(n), где n - нужное количество повторений.